# Primitive idempotents of a semisimple algebra PAP

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let A be a finite dimensional semisimple algebra over $\mathbb C$, e a primitive idempotent of A, and P any idempotent of A.

Consider the semisimple algebra PAP. I would like to prove (or disprove) that (i) eP is 0, or (ii) for some $N \in \mathbb C$, N eP is a primitive idempotent in PAP. Any idea?

Comment: Why should $PeP$ be an idempotent at all?  Consider examples with $2\times 2$ matrices, say.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, after working out some examples it seems that N PeP is an idempotent for some $N\in \mathbb C$. I edited the question.

Comment: So $A$ is an algebra specifically over $\mathbb{C}$?  Is it finite-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes indeed. Sorry for the lack of precision. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false.  For instance, if $A=M_2(\mathbb{C})$, then you could have $e=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $P=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}$, and then $eP=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is not a scalar multiple of an idempotent.

What you can say is that $A$ is a product of matrix algebras, and $e$ is a rank $1$ projection on one coordinate and $0$ on all the other coordinates.  This means that $eP$ will be $0$ on all but one coordinate and have rank at most $1$ on the last coordinate.  A matrix of rank $1$ is either a scalar multiple of a rank $1$ projection or is a nonzero nilpotent matrix, but either case is possible for $eP$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the example you took, P.e.P is 0. Could the statement be correct for PeP instead of eP?

Comment: No, you can build a similar example where $PeP$ is nilpotent using $3\times 3$ matrices.